# DIV multiple dynamic Collapsible

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to write a query(using JS, HTML and PHP) where, I try to expand or collapse contents of DIVs(which are generated dynamically). I have succeeded in writing the DIV expand and collapse query in JS. It gives me a problem. When I try to expand any div placed below Div 1, the expanded information shows only in DIV 1. How to expand in the respective Div?

I am copying the part of the code:

JS Code:

```
function toggle(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == ''){
    e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    e.style.display = '';
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="longDes">
    <p>  
        <br>
        <?php echo $rs['shortDescription'];?>
        <?php $idDiv = $rs['TITLE']; echo $idDiv;?>
        <BR> 
    </p>

    <p>
        <br>
        <a href = "#" onclick = "toggle('<?php echo $idDiv?>')">
               See More information about <?=$rs['TITLE']?></a>
        <br>
        <div id = "<?php echo $idDiv ?>" name = "<?php echo $idDiv ?>" style="display:none">
        <?php //echo "this is Buy Flag ".$rs['buyStatus']?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $rs['description']?>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Can you please help!? I am at my wits end!

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is a good one to use here. I believe the following should do what you are after:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(<?php echo $idDiv ?>).slideToggle();
});
```

This should give you a starting point. You can incorporate that into a normal JS function in an external JS file (i.e. ext.js).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Look at the question's `tags`. This is not about jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Change e.style.display == '' to **e.style.display == 'block'**
also

e.style.display = '' to **e.style.display = 'block';**

```
   function toggle(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.style.display == 'block'){
        e.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
```

Working Jsfiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/6hdre/**

hope this will help you!